# Linux or Web-based Powerpoint alternative supporting inline WYSIWYG equations?

Tags: math, presentation, slideshow

At work I am using a PC with Linux.

I also need to prepare presentation slides, that may require both math and graphical capabilities (such as drawing shapes on top of images).

- Libreoffice doesn't qualify, because it has no inline equations and no WYSIWYG equation editor.
- LaTeX is good for pure-math presentations. However, it has no equivalent of freely positioning text boxes and adding annotations on top of graphics or equations, that works fast enough. TikZ can produce beautiful results, but it is slow compared to a mouse-driven interface.
- LyX becomes favorable, when complicated equations are needed, but otherwise suffers the same drawbacks as LaTeX.

By comparison, Powerpoint (2007 or newer) provides a powerful WYSIWYG math editor, that can be used inline in text-boxes (though it lacks the support for multiline aligned equations present in Word). But at work, I can only run it through a virtual machine.

Is there some other native Linux or web-based office suite or dedicated presentation program, that overcomes these limitations?